# Why can't I assign anything to an array anymore

Tags: c++, arrays, char, iostream

I have this implementation of a linked list class (using char arrays for strange reason)

```
list_node::list_node(const std::string & input, int start, int end) {
std::cout << "1 arg constructor called" << std::endl;

letters = new char[end - start + 1];
int i = start;

for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
    letters[i] = input[i];
}

letters[i] = '\0';

std::cout << letters << std::endl;
previous = NULL;
next = NULL;
}
```

What I cannot fathom is that the first time, this method is called, it works. Thereafter, it doesn't. Stepping through the debugger in Eclipse, the body of the for loop does not execute at all! I added

```
letters[i] = '\0'
```

to make sure that my array is null-terminated, makes no difference.

I have another method which takes in a pointer to the previous node in the linked list. I just omitted it

Comment: What values do start and end have? Also check their values on the second time.

Comment: each node stores a portion of the string. (as a char array). So thats what start and end are. I am sure the values are being passed correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you don't actually want to index `letters` with `i`, since it begins at `start`. If `start` is greater than `0`, then you'll end up running over the end of the dynamically allocated array. Instead, you want:

```
letters[i - start] = input[i];
```

And then:

```
letters[i - start] = '\0'; // or end - start
```

Comment: @user929404 I've seen much worse.